# ADO.NET GetOleDbSchemaTable

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb, oledbconnection, getschematable

I'm trying to fill DataRelation collection by information, read from database.

```
DataTable schemaTable =
    oleconnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
        OleDbSchemaGuid.Foreign_Keys,
        new object[] { null, null, tablename });
```

But this info doesn't say anything about is it real foreign key constraint or just relation and, because of this, I don't know what value to set for the fourth parameter of DataRelation constructor (createConstraints).

```
public DataRelation(
    string relationName,
    DataColumn[] parentColumns,
    DataColumn[] childColumns,
    bool createConstraints
)
```

Particularly, in MS Access one could connect two tables with relation but not enforce data integrity check. Some additional research showed that such unenforced relations appear in OleDbSchemaGuid.Referential_Constraints schema table too.

I am wondering where can I get required information. Please show me the way.

Comment: for which particular database you required he information. Do you require only PK-FK relationship or the check constraints.

Comment: For MS Access. I need PK-FK relationship list (and for each of item information about is it enforced - in MS Access one can create PK-FK relationship without enforcement).

Comment: If I provide you the list of column names, table names used in relation and true/false to identify relation is enforced or not. Will it work or you need explicitly relation object.

Comment: One more query, which version of access i.e  2003, 2007 , 2010 you are using.

Comment: MS Access 2003. Yes, enforcement flag field (true/false) for each relation is sufficient for me. I tried to find such fields, but nothing of found was really what I want (even combinations of several fields wasn't).

Comment: I'm interested in retrieving this information through ADO .NET interface.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to fetch the additional attributes related to a relation in MSAccess using Ado.Net. It was possible only in VBA using DAO.

All the relations and their additional attributes are stored in `MSysRelationships` table in every version of ms-access. The field `grbit` has values for all possible attributes of a relation i.e. Enforce Referential Intigrity, Cascade Delete, Cascadde Update. Other fields of this table are self explanatory and those are same with the fields returned by GetOleDbSchemaTable method.

Some useful calculation for Grbit:

- It means if there is one to one relationship and Enforce Referential Intigrity is on then Grbit will be 0.
- It means if there is one to one relationship and Enforce Referential Intigrity is OFF then Grbit will be 3.
- It means if there is one to many relationship and Enforce Referential Intigrity is OFF then Grbit will be 2.
- It means if there is one to many relationship and Enforce Referential Intigrity is ON then Grbit will be 0.

Sample code to access the table in c#:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\mydb.mdb;");
con.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From MSysRelationships", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

See also:

- [Refer possible values of GrBit field and their meaning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff834499.aspx)
- [How GrBit is calculated](http://www.dbforums.com/4537921-post1.html)

**Note**: It's not possible to fetch the extra information related to relation in MS-Access through `GetOleDbSchemaTable`. Oledb is an wrapper only on the database and `Access` is not exposing ths information to outer world, so it's not possible to fetch the information with `ADO.net` in direct maner.

So for workaround, you need to access and manipulate only `grbit` column information of `MSysRelationships` table.

Comment: Sorry, I'm interested only in answer that shows how to retrieve this information through ADO .NET interface.

Comment: @Ruben, There is no other way to get this information other than fetching records from MSysRelationships. You get the same information from this table that is returned by GetOleDbSchemaTable.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309681
Seems easy but I got also problem in dealing with DataTable :(